# jquery form validation help required

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new to jQuery I made a form mixing html and jQuery, I would like to know how can I make some fields to "required"? here is the code

```js
btsample = $('<div id="sample" title="TITLE"/>').appendTo(ctrls).click(function() {
  $("#getsample").dialog("open")
})
$('<div id="getsample" title="TITLE">' +
  '<form><span>NAME : </span><input type="text" name="myname" ></input><br/>' +
  '<span>TEL : </span><input type="text" name="myphone"></input><br/>' +
  '<span>ADRESS : </span><input type="text" name="myaddress" ></input><br/>' +
  '<span>Email : </span><input type="text" name="myemail" ></input><br/>' +
  '<span >PROJECT NAME : </span><input type="text" name="projectName"></input><br/>' +
  '<span>ARK NAME : </span><input type="text" name="arkName"></input></form> <br/>' +
  '</div>').appendTo(ctrls).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "send": getsample
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: add `required` to the inputs you want to be required

Comment: first you want to make check click event is proper working or not ?

Comment: Your question shows [no attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) of solving the problem. If you try, you may succeed. But if you do not, you will always fail. And if you did try, without sharing our efforts with others, they may duplicate your work instead of providing a working solution.

Comment: the form works fine, @Elmer Dantas i have already tried, when i add required nothing happens the form is directly submitted before checking

Comment: Input tags shouldn't have closing tags. They should be written like `<input type="text" name="myphone">` or `<input type="text" name="myphone" />`. They should not have a closing tag. Also adding `required` should solve the problem as suggested below.

Comment: theres something missing...as @Simon mentioned you're closing your input wrongly. see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LEZ4r/2313/

Answer (score 2):

As Elmer Dantas suggested, you need to add the `required` attribute to those inputs you want to be required, like this:

```
<input type="text" name="myname" required>
```